# Which approach shows better performance: encapsulating into a method or not?

Tags: java, objective-c, performance, methods

While I am writing the code sometimes I bump in the situation when I need to choose whether I should create a separate method (the advantage is that I can use my own syntax later) or implement the complex method which already exists (also less lines of the code).

Here are the examples using different programming languages (Objective-C and Java) to explain the question.

**Objective-C example:**

```
-(double) maxValueFinder: (NSMutableArray *)data {
double max = [[data valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] doubleValue];
return maxValue;
}
```

then later:

```
...
double max = [self maxValueFinder:data];
...
```

or just every time try to call:

```
...
double max = [[data valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] doubleValue];
...
```

**Java example:**

```
public static double maxFinder (ArrayList<Double> data) {
double maxValue = Collections.max(data);
return maxValue;
}
```

then later:

```
...
double max = maxFinder(data);
...
```

or just every time try to call:

```
...
double max = Collections.max(data);
...
```

or more complex case to make the point of my question sharper:

```
//using jsoup
public static Element getElement(Document content){
Element link = content.getElementsByTag("a").first();
return link;
}
```

or every time:

```
...
Element link = content.getElementsByTag("a").first();
...
```

Which approach cost less resources (performance, memory) or it is the same?

Comment: With no disrespect I strongly advise to read this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Answer (score 2):

It absolutely doesn't matter. At least in your Java case you're uselessly recreating existing functionality, which is ridiculous.

You should first see if the functionality is contained in the standard library, then see if existing well known libraries have it, and only after that should you consider writing implementations yourself (especially for more complex functionality).

Performance has nothing to do with your question, except in the sense that the more time you spend on recreating existing functionality, the less time you have left for actual new code (therefore lowering your programming performance).

As for creating wrapper methods, that can be useful in some cases, especially if the actual method calls are often chained and you find yourself having more and more of those in the code. But there's a delicate difference between code clarity and writing excessive code.

```
public void parseHtml() {
    parseFirstPart();
    parseSecondPart();
    parseThirdPart();
}
```

If we assume that each `parse` method only contains 1 or maybe 2 method calls then adding these additional methods is most likely useless, since the same thing can be achieved by proper commenting. If the `parse` methods contain a lot of calls, it makes sense to extract methods out of them. There's no rule about it, it's a skill you learn while you program (and of course depends a lot on what you view as *beautiful* code.

Comment: I think you have the main point, but sometimes it happens that functionality  is more complex than in my example like using jsoup: Element link = content.getElementsByTag("a").first();. Moreover, when you recreate existed functionality, you can remember personal syntax more easily, especially when you need to use that method a lot.

Comment: That's a different thing. There's nothing wrong with making a wrapper, such as `getFirstLink(foo)` which would execute `foo.getElementsByTag("a").first();`. You're not rewriting functionality there unlike in your example.

Comment: Does the program process the whole code of the method every time I call it?

Comment: What do you mean by "process the whole code". It executes the whole code of course. Michal already directed you to read about `premature optimization`, I recommend the same. There's no reason to worry about performance in such irrelevant cases. A method call doesn't take a lot of time, and the JIT can inline them if it chooses.

Answer (score -1):

- It's absolutely useless to recreating existing functionality.
- Because these function is already implement in library.
- If you talk about performance then both cases you are loading same line
  double maxValue = Collections.max(data);
- Performance is not matter in both cases because you are loading same code.